# How to create a toolbar from resources?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, toolbar

I Created a toolbar resource (IDR_TOOLBAR) using resource editor, how can I add it to a window using basic Win32 APIs?

Comment: @MitchWheat I dont't want to use CreateToolbarEx because MSDN says it's deprecated. I've been searching for a long time, but all I find are using an existed GUI lib or load bitmaps then add buttons one by one, I don't know if I can simply load toolbar and add it to a window.

Comment: The [`CreateToolbarEx` function documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787469.aspx) (you know, the one you read that told you the function was deprecated) also says: *"Use [`CreateWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) instead. For examples, see [Using Toolbar Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760446.aspx)."* Did that not help you?

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, that works, but I can’t use my “Toolbar Resource” (There isn't such thing) to create toolbar.

Comment: That's correct. There is no such thing as a "toolbar resource". It's quite unclear how you even ended up with one, unless you're using a library like MFC (in which you wouldn't be calling `CreateToolbarEx` or any of the SDK functions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "Toolbar resource" thing for WIN32 API.

Toolbar resources are artifacts for MFC classes like `CToolbar` and the like.
It actually consist in a bitmap (contaning the stripe of the images, and having the same ID of the toolbar) and a `RT_TOOLBAR` (actually `MAKEINTRESOURCE(241)`) resource type that is a linear vector containing the commands to be mapped to the images. You can read it as such with `FindResource` / `LoadResource`.